# Two Enterprise Root CA's on same domain

Tags: domain-controller, certificate-authority

I am currently replacing 4 2012 domain controllers with 4 new 2022 domain controllers. I have run into an issue with the certificate authority as there were two enterprise root CA's installed on the domain. 3/4 of the new domain controllers received their domain controller cert from a CA that I will need to remove. The other CA will be migrated to one of the new domain controllers. What is the process to clean this mess up? Is there a way to get the correct CA to reissue domain controller certificates or does it even matter? If I just remove the role on the CA that I no longer want to be a CA will the certificates that it issued still be good? What about renewal of the domain controller certificates? I find it difficult to locate information on this topic online so any help is appreciated.

I am including a screenshot of the certificates I am referring to. Each of these certs were issued on the day the server was promoted to a domain controller.

[image]